# Distribution of predicted probability is heavily skewed

Tags: xgboost

I'm a beginner here. I'm just trying to use a xgboost method for classification learning problem. My data is 70-30 unbalanced. But I ran into a problem about the distribution of predicted probability is heavily skewed as a picture below. I need an advice to solve this one.

[image]

Comment: Question: "The ouputs I want to be probability of each account." What account? Please give more context.

Comment: I mean those are predicted probabilities outputs.

Comment: What is your goal - to classify or to obtain a probability estimate for each class? Why is the skewness in predicted probability outputs for the training set a problem to you?

Comment: My goal focus on F1 score, and I just want to clarify the model probabilities outputs here are valid. After I look back my data with 70:30 unbalanced, and doing some features distribution survey. Beside, probabilities distribution of testing sets  are also  same as the training.  So I think that's not a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about this problem with an example. Suppose that you're trying to predict fraudulent credit card transactions. Since genuine transactions are more frequent than fraudulent transactions (imagine 1% of transactions are fraudulent), the probability of a randomly selected transaction being a fraud is going to be really small, right?

Now suppose that we have a set of 10000 transactions and we have  way of calculating the probability of fraud in each one of them. If we compute the probabilities and make a density plot of these probabilities, we'll observe a very skewed distribution (lots of transactions will have small fraud probabilities).

That's what happening in you example. Your model is estimating the probability of an event that is probably rare (I take this from your observation that the dataset is unbalanced, 70/30). Therefore, you don't need to "fix" your distribution.

Although, if you're using this probability as a score, for example, it may be easier to work with a less skewed distribuition. In that case, you can apply some [monotonic transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) to your probabilities. That type of transformation will change the distribuition of your variable (probability estimate from the model) without changig the ordering, e.g, if an onbservation A has smaller probability than an observation B, the score after the transformation will mantain this A < B ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation in details. I will try your suggestion.